# import Google Analytic tracking code

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

will there be a problem when importing a javascript code for  Google Analytic tracking code.

**if needed,heres my .js code**

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I have trouble in creating a new .js file for this. Please explain about this.

Comment: You just need to add that code snippet to your HTML, preferably right before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: cant i make it as external

Comment: Sure, take everything inside the `<script>` tags and put that into a separate file called `analytics.js` or whatever then add `<script src="analytics.js"></script>` to your HTML file...preferably right before the closing `</body>` tag. Probably better to just drop the snippet directly into your HTML file though to make 1 less HTTP request

Comment: It will only create a problem, if you need to tweak `pageview` call for different pages ;)

Comment: that means i need to paste that code for every page instead of external linking.